# Return specific segment from Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a big chunk of text I am scanning through and I am searching with a regex that is prefixed by some text.

```
var1 = textchunk.match(/thedata=(\d{6})/)
```

My result from `var1` would return something like:

```
thedata=123456
```

How do I only return the number part of the search so in the example above just 123456 without taking `var1` and then stripping `thedata=` off in a line below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect just one match in the string, you may use your own code and access the *`captures`* property and get the *`first`* item (since the data you need is captured with the first set of unescaped parentheses that form a *capturing group*):

```
textchunk.match(/thedata=(\d{6})/).captures.first
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/iFQNyH)

If you have multiple matches, just use `scan`:

```
textchunk.scan(/thedata=(\d{6})/)
```

NOTE: to only match `thedata=` followed with *exactly* 6 digits, add a word boundary:

```
/thedata=(\d{6})\b/
                ^^
```

or a lookahead (if there can be word chars after 6 digits other than digits):

```
/thedata=(\d{6})(?!\d)/
                ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ textchunk = 'garbage=42 thedata=123456'
#⇒ "garbage=42 thedata=123456"
▶ textchunk[/thedata=(\d{6})/, 1]
#⇒ "123456"
▶ textchunk[/(?<=thedata=)\d{6}/]
#⇒ "123456"
```

The latter uses [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).